# How to check if an array contains another object's values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a function that returns true if all the array values are present in an object values.

I have transformed the object values into a new array called `newArray`; but my question is how can I compare between the given array and the new array?

```
const compare = function (array, object) {
    const newArray =Object.values(object)
    //compare here and return true/false
};  

compare(["one", "two", "three"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }); // => true
compare(["one", "two", "four"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }); // => false
```

Comment: `Object.values(object).every(val => array.indexOf(val) !== -1)`

Comment: What should `compare(["one", "three", "two"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" });` give (index of "three" here doesn't align with the key-index in the object)

Comment: do you have only unique values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I transformed the object values into a new array

I think a `Set` would be even better, since it has a [`has` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) with sub-linear performance and the semantics are nice and clear. But the easiest way to get to a `Set` is via an array, so... :-)

Once you have the `Set`, it's a matter of looping, in this case probably with [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
const compare = (array, object) => {
    const values = new Set(Object.values(object));
    return array.every(v => values.has(v));
};
```

`every` returns `true` if the callback always returns a truthy value, or returns `false` the first time the callback returns a falsy value (short-circuiting at that point, no reason to keep looking if the answer is "no").

If you want to stick with an array, though, you could use `includes` in the `every`. It has linear performance, but in 99.9999% of situations, the performance isn't critical anyway:

```
const compare = (array, object) => {
    const values = Object.values(object);
    return array.every(v => values.includes(v));
};
```

---

As [Nina points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593598/157247), adding a check that the lengths match would short-circuit faster. Here's what that looks like for both of the above:

Set:

```
const compare = (array, object) => {
    const valuesArray = Object.values(object);
    if (valuesArray.length !== array.length) {
        return false;
    }
    const values = new Set(valuesArray);
    return array.every(v => values.has(v));
};
```

Array:

```
const compare = (array, object) => {
    const values = Object.values(object);
    return array.length === values.length && array.every(v => values.includes(v));
};
```

You could go even further and add

```
if (array.length === 0) {
    return true;
}
```

at the very beginning of both.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort both arrays and then check that they have the same length and loop through both at the same time comparing the two elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const compare = (array, object) => {
    return Object.values(object).reduce((res, cur) => {
      return res && array.includes(cur);
    }, 1);
};  

console.log(compare(["one", "two", "three"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" })); // => true
console.log(compare(["one", "two", "four"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" })); // => false
```

Comment: You *can*, but it doesn't short-circuit. That won't matter often, though. It also doesn't offer any semantic information to the reader, vs. `every` which calls out exactly what's being done.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to check the length of the array and values as well.

```js
const
    compare = (array, object) => {
        const values = Object.values(object)
        return array.length === values.length && values.every(v => array.includes(v));
    };


console.log(compare(["one", "two", "three"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" })); //  true
console.log(compare(["one", "two", "four"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" })); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const compare = (array, object) => Object.values(object).every(n => array.includes(n));
```